# Issues uploading entities via a CSV file in Dialogflow CX

Tags: csv, upload, entities, dialogflow-cx, csv-import

I am having difficulties uploading a CSV file to Dialogflow CX to define entities and their synonyms. Despite following the recommendations on the format of CSV files, I encounter an error message stating "Wrong CSV format: no required value line 1" each time I attempt to upload the file.

I have tried several things to address this issue. First, I checked the format of my CSV file to ensure it aligns with Dialogflow's specifications. I also ensured my CSV file is encoded in UTF-8 and that the field and string delimiters are correctly set. Additionally, I attempted to upload the CSV file without making any modifications after downloading it from Dialogflow. In all these cases, I expected the CSV file to upload without issues. However, despite receiving a message that the upload was successful (green OK), the entities are not reflected in my Dialogflow agent.